# Improve performance in Merge statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, merge

I have below merge query which is working fine for small datasets but for example for `800000k` rows its taking more than 40 minutes for execution.

In this Merge query i am trying to perfrom Delta import logic using `Insert/Update/Delete`. For new data with combination of Unique `column(ID_LL_ ID_UU, TKR)` i want to insert data otherwise update. Delete with delete the data from `test_rua_mer` table  which does not exist in `test_rua` table.

How can i improve perfromance in this query ? Is there any alternative way of writing this query efficiently ?

```
MERGE
  INTO TEST_RUA_MER T
  USING (
         SELECT  T.ROWID T_RID,
                 CASE
                   WHEN S.ROWID IS NULL THEN 1
                   WHEN     DECODE(S.CLASS,T.CLASS,1) = 1
                        AND
                            DECODE(S.NAME,T.NAME,1) = 1
                     THEN 1
                 END DELETE_FLAG,
                 S.*
           FROM      TEST_RUA S
                 FULL JOIN
                     TEST_RUA_MER T
                   ON(
                          DECODE(T.ID_LL,S.ID_LL,1) = 1
                      AND
                          DECODE(T.ID_UU,S.ID_UU,1) = 1
                      AND
                          DECODE(T.TKR,S.TKR,1) = 1
                     )
        ) S
  ON (
          T.ROWID = S.T_RID
     )
  WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
      UPDATE
         SET T.CLASS = S.CLASS,
             T.NAME  = S.NAME
      DELETE WHERE S.DELETE_FLAG = 1
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
      INSERT
      VALUES(
             S.CLASS,
             S.ID_LL,
             S.ID_UU,
             S.TKR,
             S.NAME
            )
```

Comment: Can you have the query without a FULL JOIN, may be that could help you or did you try a Update  statement

Comment: where is the bottle neck ? execution plan show any sign ?

Comment: @hkandpal update works faster..instead FULL join what else i can use to keep the logic of the query same ?

Comment: @eshirvana i check the explain plan and it suggest  most of the cpu cost is occuring by : HASH JOIN (RIGHT OUTER)
SYS.  VIEW
HASH JOIN (OUTER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the `DECODE` function instead of just checking if the values are equal? This should return the same results and hopefully improve performance as long as the columns being used in the joins are properly indexed.

```sql
MERGE INTO TEST_RUA_MER T
     USING (SELECT T.ROWID    T_RID,
                   CASE
                       WHEN S.ROWID IS NULL THEN 1
                       WHEN S.CLASS = T.CLASS AND S.NAME = T.NAME THEN 1
                   END        DELETE_FLAG,
                   S.*
              FROM TEST_RUA  S
                   FULL JOIN TEST_RUA_MER T
                       ON (T.ID_LL = S.ID_LL AND T.ID_UU = S.ID_UU AND T.TKR = S.TKR)) S
        ON (T.ROWID = S.T_RID)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE SET T.CLASS = S.CLASS, T.NAME = S.NAME
    DELETE
             WHERE S.DELETE_FLAG = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT     VALUES (S.CLASS,
                       S.ID_LL,
                       S.ID_UU,
                       S.TKR,
                       S.NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks the query is working faster but the problem is now query logic has been changed...now its not handling null value for unique values ID_LL or ID_UU or TKR...so when any of this values is null its not checking delta logic

Comment: The distinct advantage of `decode` is that it treats `null` as "equal" to `null` - unlike a direct equality check. Instead of asking the OP, if you are not familiar with `decode`, you could just do a quick search to find out.

Comment: @mathguy actually i was bit confused about why the unique combination is not handling null value now because OP has written direct eaulity check same like decode..

Comment: Actually as i removed the Decode part so its not handling null values correctly for delta logic...for example when there is null value in any fields its not deleting the data from TEST_RUA_MER table even if the row is same like TEST_RUA table

Comment: can we create Delete separately here to reduce the performance but again question is do we need to handle null values in delete or using existing oracle funstion if any ?

Comment: @Symonds, you can use `NVL` to handle the null values. `NVL` should not impact performance as much as `DECODE`